# Showing thumbnails of product based on the available colors and type of material in php

Tags: php

In my website I have a page where I am showing the list of products for sale. Its a shopping website. So for each product, i am trying to show the thumbnails of that product based of color and material. for example for Product A, there are 3 colors available- Black, Brown and Blue and they are in two material types- material A and material B. In which only black is available in both the materials. SO basically, I should get 4 thumbnail pictures, but I am getting only 3. So I have implemented the following code and after that code I am getting the thumbnails for all the colors and all the materials. That is, I got 2 thumbnails for black, 2 for blue and brown(even though they are not available in both the materials). I know I need to put some condition, but don't know what to do? help is appreciated.

**Products.php**

```
<?foreach ($item->getMaterialTypes() as $materials){
      foreach($item->getColors() as $colors){ ?>
           <li>
                <a class="thumbnails" title="<?=$colors->name?>" data-product="<?=$item->id?>" data-color="<?=$colors->id?>" data-color-name="<?=$colors->name?> - <?=$materials->name?>">
                     <img src="<?=$item->getImage(null, $colors->id)?>"/>
                 </a>
           </li>
       <?}
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check for each product if that material is available in each color:

```
<?foreach ($item->getMaterialTypes() as $materials){
      foreach($item->getColors() as $colors){ 
           if(isProductMaterialAvailableWith($colors->id)) {?>
           <li>
                <a class="thumbnails" title="<?=$colors->name?>" data-product="<?=$item->id?>" data-color="<?=$colors->id?>" data-color-name="<?=$colors->name?> - <?=$materials->name?>">
                     <img src="<?=$item->getImage(null, $colors->id)?>"/>
                 </a>
           </li>
       <?  }
      }
}?>
```

isProductMaterialAvailableWith($colors->id) should be a function that checks it. I cannot provide an example of this function because I don't have enough information about your database.

Comment: I downvoted because you're trying to build an answer over assumptions, rather than trying to learn about facts.